# rails 3 - devise block user to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have something in mind, i have some user types, Building owner, building manager.

I want to create user as building manager, but i dont want they have access to login system. this user are only for some selectbox in my website, but i need to show them in my user index page.

what i think i can do is create normal user and with a before_save i create a new data in another table.

In a request i need to be able to setup in my building form more than one building manager. maybe the best are with nested form.. I think i will need to add building id to my user table. maybe they can be assigned more than one building.

for now, my db structure are like this :

```
table users with user data (username, password, email, first and last name, phone)
table usertype have userid, typename and accesslvl
```

But this problem give me some managing problem. They will not be associated with user data.

How can i resolve this? Does Device can block some user? I searched in the Devise docs, but nothing found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an approach where admin users can approve other user accounts for login. You could use a similar approach but programmatically approve the accounts you actually want to allow logins for. Details are here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

Comment: Thanks, i missed this solution. Is it possible to remove password validation if i have selectbox selected to building manager too? i hide it with jquery, but always ask to enter password, on create and edit form.. thanks!

Comment: If these accounts will be inactive anyway, then security doesn't matter. Perhaps just create a hidden field with a default password in it for this situation (or you could create the password in the controller before calling create on the model).

Comment: Thinking further, you could put the code to set a default password into a "before_create" callback in the user model and use a condition to only do so if it is a building manager. This would probably be the tidiest approach.